# DOM usage in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I was going through the soce code of Hibernate 4.1 And I noticed that it was using DOM instead of JAXB for converting the XMLs. I was thinking JAXB would be a easier way to do it because of the simplicity of it. Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 0):

JAXB is obviously slower than DOM. So it might be for a performance reason. Also, DOM is more flexible than JAXB.

Comment: I admit JAXB is slower. But this going to be a one time conversion which is going to happen when the configuration gets loaded. So the overall performance will not take a hit as the files are loaded during the application startup not while servicing the requests

Comment: It depends what you are comparing.  A JAXB conversion includes converting instances of `String` to specific types such as `int` or `Date`, and gives you a domain model.  Even if the DOM parse was faster (benchmark required), you still need to factor in all the DOM interactions to have a fair comparison.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that Hibernate was trying to avoid a dependency on the `javax.xml.bind` APIs as there code was probably written at a time when they were baselined on Java SE 5.